# Regex for Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, grep

I need a regex to match using `egrep` which checks for a pattern like the following `1_0_5` in a long **request** string. If we consider the pattern as `a_b_c`. I want **b** to be anything apart from 2, 3, 4 and 13.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: **Answer:** Use `grep -E '(?!)'` or `grep -P '(?!)'`, and make sure to use `' '` or it won't like the `!`.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
grep -P '\b[^_]+_(?!(2|3|4|13)_)[^_]+_[^_]+\b' myfile
```

If your terms are all digits, refine it to this:

```
grep -P '\b\d+_(?!(2|3|4|13)_)\d+_\d+\b' myfile
```

Note the `-P` flag to turn on perl comparability, which allows look aheads

Answer (score 1):

egrep doesn't support lookaheads.

You can use `grep -P` (PCRE)

```
grep -P '^[0-9]*_(?!(2|3|4|13)_)[0-9]*_[0-9]*$' file
```

OR else if above pattern is found in the middle of a string then use word boundaries instead of line start/end anchors:

```
grep -P '\b[0-9]*_(?!(2|3|4|13)_)[0-9]*_[0-9]*\b' file
```

Comment: That would exclude a_22_c - I think the neg look ahead should include the ending underscore. It would also match `a_2_c a_x_c` which would include an unwanted hit

Comment: @Bohemian: Thanks good point, I corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity and simplicity:

```
awk '/a_[^_]+_c/ && !/a_(2|3|4|13)_c/' file
```

It would help us to help you, though, if you posted some sample input and expected output.